# SwiftUI TextEditor Disable AutoCapitalization

Tags: swiftui, ios14

As mentioned in the title....how can I turn off autocapitalization in the new SwiftUI TextEditor?

I tried this but it doesn't work and just ignores the modifier

```
TextEditor(text: $comment)
      .autocapitalization(.none)
      .disableAutocorrection(true)
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm also seeing the same thing

Comment: I checked my code and based on that it looks like I didn't....I think I just rolled with whatever the default was...

Comment: That's unfortunate. I've resigned to make it all lowercased which is better than nothing... Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: yeah, I actually used uikit and other things like uicollectionview (for chat) at times because swiftui doesn't cover all cases...but they do allow interop in case you need to go with a custom design...just takes more work but you have more control.